# Passing Session variables between ASP and ASP.net in different frames

Tags: asp.net, asp-classic

I am trying to migrate a web based logging system from a windows 2003 server to a 2012 R2 server for a client, so IIS6 to IIS 8.5
This system is old and a mish-mash of classic ASP and ASP.net VB, opening in 3 frames.

The problem I am having is that the system (under IIS6) was able to pass Session("variables") between the ASP and ASP.net pages, but under IIS8.5, it refuses to do this.

Is this possible?

Comment: Is your session storage in process or out of process?

Comment: I have tried both "In process" and on a local State Server. Both the ASP and ASP.net are running in the same application pool too.

Comment: I'm surprised this worked in IIS6 - maybe there was a bespoke solution in place which you hadn't discovered.  A popular hack is to use zero size iframes to pass session variables from one type of page to the other.  Alternatively look at the solution suggested on msdn, which involved writing the variables to a database.  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa479313.aspx